# Inline assembly: clarification of constraint modifiers

Tags: c, assembly, arm, constraints, inline-assembly

Two questions:

(1) If I understand ARM inline assembly correctly, a constraint of "r" says that the instruction operand can only be a core register and that by default is a read-only operand. However, I've noticed that if the same instruction has an output operand with the constraint "=r", the compiler may re-use the same register. This seems to violate the "read-only" attribute. So my question is: Does "read-only" refer to the register, or to the C variable that it is connected to?

(2) Is it correct to say that presence of "&" in the constraint of "=&r" simply requires that the register chosen for the output operand must not be the same as one of the input operand registers? My question relates to the code below used to compute the integer power function: i.e., are the "&" constraint modifiers necessary/appropriate?

```
asm (
"    MOV   %[power],1                \n\t"
"loop%=:                             \n\t"
"    CBZ   %[exp],done%=             \n\t"
"    LSRS  %[exp],%[exp],1           \n\t"
"    IT    CS                        \n\t"
"    MULCS %[power],%[power],%[base] \n\t"
"    MUL   %[base],%[base],%[base]   \n\t"
"    B     loop%=                    \n\t"
"done%=:                                 "
: [power] "+&r" (power)
  [base]  "+&r" (base)
  [exp]   "+&r" (exp)
:
: "cc"
) ;
```

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: No, "r" doesn't mean read-only, it just means "general purpose register". Arguments that you specify in the input list are read only, no matter what constraint you use.

Comment: See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) for details about input parameters and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) for details of simple constraints (like `"r"`).  You might also want to look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) for constraints specific to the "ARM Family."

Answer (score 2):

Read-only refers to the use of the operand in assembly code. The assembly code can only read from the operand, and it must do so before any normal output operand (not an early clobber or a read/write operand) is written. This is because, as you've seen, the same register can be allocated to both an input and output operand. The assumption is that inputs are fully consumed before any output is written, which is normally the case for an assembly instruction.

I don't think using an early-clobber modifier `&` with an read/write modifier `+` has any effect since a register allocated to a read/write operand can't be used for anything else.

Here's how I'd write your code:

```
unsigned power = 1;
asm (
    "    CBZ   %[exp],done%=             \n\t"
    "loop%=:                             \n\t"
    "    LSRS  %[exp],%[exp],1           \n\t"
    "    IT    CS                        \n\t"
    "    MULCS %[power],%[power],%[base] \n\t"
    "    MUL   %[base],%[base],%[base]   \n\t"
    "    BNE   loop%=                    \n\t"
    "done%=:                                 "
    : [power] "+r" (power),
      [base]  "+r" (base),
      [exp]   "+r" (exp)
    :
    : "cc"
    ) ;
```

Note the transformation of putting the loop test at the end of the loop, saving one instruction. Without it the code doesn't have any obvious improvement over what the compiler can generate.  I also let the compiler do the initialization of the register used for the `power` operand.  There's a small chance it will be able to allocate a register that already has the value 1 in it.

Comment: The combination of early-clobber and read-write is significant as if 2 inputs have the same value they can be the same register.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you for the clarification. Just to be sure that I have it right, would it be correct to say that the choice between "=r" and "+r" for an output operand comes down to how the corresponding register is ***first*** used in the assembly template? I.e.,

**"=r":  The first use of the register is as a write-only output of an instruction.**

*The register may be re-used later by another instruction as an input or output. Adding an early clobber constraint (e.g., "=&r") prevents the compiler from assigning a register that was previously used as an input operand.*

**"+r":  The first use of the register is as an input to an instruction, but the register is used again later as an output.**

Best,

Dan

Comment: I think I prefer "`"=r"(x)`: On input to the asm, the contents of this register are undefined (unless combined with a matching input constraint), and on output, the register will contain the value for the variable `x`. And "`"+r"(x)`: The existing value of `x` is passed as input, which may be updated by the asm instructions."  And "See also the `&` modifier to prevent input and output constraints from sharing registers."

Comment: David, I'm confused by "(unless combined with a matching input constraint)". I thought that anything listed as an Input Operand was by definition "read-only" and thus would be in conflict with listing the same thing as an Output Operand. Or do I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: As discussed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands), input constraints can be digits.  So `asm("" : "=r"(x) : "0" (y));`  means that `y` is an input and goes into the same place as parameter #0.  Or to put it another way: On input, the register will contain `y`, and on output it will contain `x`.  This also means that `asm("" : "=r"(x) : "0" (x));` is a synonym for `asm("" : "+r"(x));`.

Comment: For an entertaining and educational bit of code (if not particularly practical), look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24841962/2189500) which allows you to 'swap' the values of 2 variables without using a single line of assembler.  And yes, I'm stretching the definition of 'swap.'  A lot.  For example if you printf the 2 variables, 'swap' them, then printf them again, while *you* may not have to write any assembler, the compiler will just end up doing it for you.