# How to write a short block of inline gnu extended assembly to swap the values of two integer variables?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, gnu, inline-assembly

For entertainment, I am learning gnu extended assembly using AT&T syntax for x86 with a 32bit Linux target. I have just spent the last three hours coding two possible solutions to my challenge of swapping the values of two integer variables `a` and `b`, and neither of my solutions completely solved my problem. First, let's look at my TODO obstacle in some more detail:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 1;
    printf("a is %d, b is %d\n", a, b);
    // TODO: swap a and b using extended assembly, and do not modify the program in any other way
    printf("a is %d, b is %d\n", a, b);
}
```

After reading [this HOWTO](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html), I wrote the following inline extended assembler code. Here is my first attempt at swapping the integers:

```
asm volatile("movl %0, %%eax;"
    "movl %1, %%ecx;"
    "movl %%ecx, %0;"
  : "=r" (a)
  : "r" (b)
  : "%eax", "%ecx");

asm volatile("movl %%eax, %0;"
  : "=r" (b)
  : "r" (a)
  : "%eax", "%ecx");
```

My reasoning was that to set a = b, I needed an extended assembly call that was separated from the assembly to set b = a. So I wrote the two extended assembly calls, compiled my code, i.e., gcc -m32 asmPractice.c, and ran a.out. The results were as follows:

> a is 2, b is 1
>
> a is 1, b is 1

Seeing how that did not work properly, I then decided to combine the two extended assembler calls, and wrote this:

```
asm volatile("movl %0, %%eax;"
    "movl %1, %%ecx;"
    "movl %%ecx, %0;"
    "movl %%eax, %1;"
  : "=r" (a)
  : "r" (b));
```

After recompiling and linking, my code still does not correctly swap both values. See for yourself. Here are my results:

> a is 2, b is 1
>
> a is 1, b is 1

Comment: Since you are passing registers you could just do `xchg %0, %1` . Using moves you only need 1 temporary register. Copy %0 to that register. Then  copy %1 to %0 and then copy the temp register to %1. The temporary will need to be listed in the clobber list

Comment: Also see the XOR swap algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: Your existing inline assembly also has the problem that `a` and `b` are both inputs and output. So **both** should be using a read write constraint of `"+r"`

Comment: You can also get the compiler to choose the temporary register by passing a dummy variable into the template using an output constraint.

Comment: If you want to use `mov` (rather than the simpler `xchg` instruction) then it would look like `int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int dummy;
  asm ("movl %0, %2\n\t"
    "movl %1, %0\n\t"
    "movl %2, %1;"
  : "+r" (a), "+r" (b), "=r"(dummy));` . Using `xchg` would look like `asm ("xchg %0, %1"
  : "+r" (a), "+r" (b));`

Comment: How about something that uses no instructions at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841962/2189500

Comment: lol @DavidWohlferd : that was my next comment. There is a natural progression to the empty template. You beat me to it

Comment: The logical progression after that is to not use inline assemble at all lol

Comment: "that was my next comment" You, me, Peter.  Seems like everyone who plays with extended asm realizes this at some point.  "not use inline assemble" - Oh yeah, that reminds me: There are [reasons](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) not to use inline asm.  If the goal is entertainment (as OP says), then have at it.  It's interesting, challenging, powerful, gives insight into how the compiler sees the world, etc.  But don't be seduced into using it in real code.

Comment: @Chris: See the x86 tag wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), and also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.  I'd recommend learning x86 assembly separately from learning GNU C inline assembly, because to use it correctly you have to already understand assembly and compilers to write constraints correctly.  Make separate functions that you call from C.

Comment: You don't need `volatile` because the only function of the asm is to produce its outputs.  You *want* the compiler to optimize it away if the outputs are unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some solutions from the comments:

**Solution #0 (best option):  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**
Even the zero-instruction solution defeats constant-propagation, and any other optimization that involves gcc knowing anything about the value.  It also forces the compiler to have both variables in  registers at the same time at that point.  Always keep these downsides in mind when considering using inline-asm instead of builtins / intrinsics.

**Solution #1: x86 `xchg`**, no scratch regs, and works in both AT&T and Intel-syntax modes.  [Costs about the same as 3 `mov` instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures/45870933#45870933) on most Intel CPUs, or only 2 uops on some AMD.

```
asm("xchg %0, %1;" : "+r" (a), "+r" (b));
```

**Solution #2: purely using GNU C inline asm constraints.**  (Bonus: portable to all architectures)

```
asm("" : "=r" (a), "=r" (b) : "1" (a), "0" (b));
```

---

See all three solutions in action [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'int+swap_noasm(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++int+tmp+%3D+b%3B%0A++b+%3D+a%3B%0A++a+%3D+tmp%3B%0A++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+swap_xchg(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++asm(%22xchg+%250,+%251%3B%22+:+%22%2B%25r%22+(a),+%22%2Br%22+(b))%3B%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+swap_constraints(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++asm(%22%22+:+%22%3Dr%22+(a),+%22%3Dr%22+(b)+:+%221%22+(a),+%220%22+(b))%3B%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+Demonstrate+the+optimization-defeating+behaviour:%0Aint+swap_constraints_constants(void)+%7B%0A++int+a+%3D+10,+b+%3D+20%3B%0A++return+swap_constraints(a,+b)+%2B+15%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+swap_noasm_constants(void)+%7B%0A++int+a+%3D+10,+b+%3D+20%3B%0A++return+swap_noasm(a,+b)+%2B+15%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:99.99999999999999,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), including examples of them defeating optimization:

```
int swap_constraints(int a, int b) {
    asm("" : "=r" (a), "=r" (b) : "1" (a), "0" (b));
    return a;
}

// Demonstrate the optimization-defeating behaviour:
int swap_constraints_constants(void) {
  int a = 10, b = 20;
  return swap_constraints(a, b) + 15;
}

swap_constraints_constants:
    movl    $10, %edx
    movl    $20, %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    ret
```

vs. with a pure C swap:

```
swap_noasm_constants:
    movl    $35, %eax    # the add is done at compile-time, and `a` is optimized away as unused.
    ret
```

Comment: You don't need an early-clobber, because `xchg` is a single instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes I made a typo in my comment. Was meant to be % not & since I was talking about commutative properties. He propagated my typo to the answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I thought [commutative](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) only applied to inputs (aka "read-only operands").

Comment: Yes, that's a good point @DavidWohlferd . That is what the docs say but I'm not entirely sure they are correct. GCC won't complain and I think I had observed a change in behavior in generated code in the past. Might have to ask the GCC mailing list about it lol

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I don't think it gains you anything to tell the compiler they're commutative.  You're already using the same `"+r"` constraint for both, so it can pick any register it wants.  It would be relevant for `"+%a"` and `"+d"`, though.  Update: https://godbolt.org/g/HxSVHQ  `"+%S"(a)` doesn't work as commutative.  The compiler still puts `a` into RSI instead of using `b` which is already there.

Comment: @Chris: I expanded your answer a bunch.  I could have posted that as my own answer, but your answer already had the right framework to add some stuff.  (I intended to just change `&` to `%`...)  Anyway, roll back if you don't like it, and I can post my own.

Comment: Hmm, my example worked fine for testing, but it makes a poor example, or at least badly named functions.  `swap_constraints` uses an asm swap, but only returns the resulting `a`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:   I noticed super-weird behaviour.  In a file by itself, swap with a `"+%S"(a)` constraint produced extra instructions.  But at the bottom of the godbolt link I edited into this answer, it doesn't!  Somehow gcc compiles the exact same function differently depending on what it did earlier.  (I think it's taking advantage of the fact that `b` is unused after the asm, since it's not like that if I `return a+b`)

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  Actually I think gcc7.2 maybe is looking inside the inline-asm and recognizing the `xchg`.  But only when the string is exactly `"xchg %0, %1;"` including the `;`, and with no extra space (leading space, or extra space between the `xchg` and the `%0` give the expected 2-instruction setup.  https://godbolt.org/g/gb6EEf.   I can reproduce this with gcc7.1 on my desktop.  I thought the fact that the compiler doesn't look at / understand the asm string was an absolute for GNU C inline asm.  So maybe this is a compiler bug.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ah, it was triggered by being in the same compilation unit as another function that used the same string with different constraints first.  Definitely a bug.  Reporting it.

Comment: "not entirely sure [the docs] are correct" Ahh, so for those who don't find writing inline asm challenging enough, you can always toss in some undocumented behavior...  Hopefully all this has driven home the point to OP that using inline asm is *tricky*.  Even the long-time experts struggle with it, even with absurdly simple examples.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Linus was a user of some of those undocumented (at the time) features lol. `P` and `p` constraints come to mind. lol

Comment: @MichaelPetch: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82001 in case you're interested.  It only happens when the whole function is identical other than asm register constraints, and with `-O2` or higher.  Regression introduced in gcc5.0.  Probably some kind of identical-function folding doesn't check constraints carefully enough.