# GCC inline assembly with stack operation

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, stack-memory

I am in need of such a inline assembly code:

- I have **a pair**(so, it is balanced) of push/pop operation inside the assembly
- I also have a variable in memory (so, not register) as input

like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("push %%eax\n\t"
        // ... some operations that use ECX as a temporary
        "mov %0, %%ecx\n\t"
        // ... some other operation
        "pop %%eax"
: : "m"(foo));
// foo is my local variable, that is to say, on stack
```

When disassembling the compiled code, the compiler give the memory address like `0xc(%esp)`, it is relative to `esp`, hence, this fragment of code will not works correctly since I have a `push` operation before `mov`.
Therefore, how can I tell the compile I do not like the `foo` relative to `esp`, but any thing like `-8(%ebp)` relative to ebp.

P.S. You may suggest that **I can put `eax` inside the Clobbers, but it is just a sample code**.  I don't like to show the full reason why I don't accept this solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modifying ESP inside inline-asm should generally be avoided when you have any memory inputs / outputs, so you don't have to disable optimizations or force the compiler to make a stack-frame with EBP some other way.  One major advantage is that **you (or the compiler) can then use EBP as an extra free register**; potentially a significant speedup if you're already having to spill/reload stuff.  If you're writing inline asm, presumably this is a hotspot so it's worth spending the extra code-size to use ESP-relative addressing modes.

In x86-64 code, there's an added obstacle to using push/pop safely, because [you can't tell the compiler you want to clobber the red-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380992/inline-assembly-that-clobbers-the-red-zone) below RSP.  (You can compile with `-mno-red-zone`, but there's no way to disable it from the C source.)  You can get problems [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm) where you clobber the compiler's data on the stack.  No 32-bit x86 ABI has a red-zone, though, so this only applies to x86-64 System V.  (Or non-x86 ISAs with a red-zone.)

You only need `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` for that function if you want to do asm-only stuff like `push` as a stack data structure, so there's a variable amount of push.  Or maybe if optimizing for code-size.

You can always write a whole non-inline function in asm and put it in a separate file, then you have full control.  But only do that if your function is large enough to be worth the call/ret overhead, e.g. if it includes a whole loop; don't make the compiler `call` a short non-looping function inside a C inner loop, destroying all the call-clobbered registers and having to make sure globals are in sync.

---

It seems you're using `push` / `pop` inside inline asm because you don't have enough registers, and need to save/reload something.  **You don't need to use push/pop for save/restore.  Instead, use dummy output operands with `"=m"` constraints to get the compiler to allocate stack space for you**, and use `mov` to/from those slots.  (Of course you're not limited to `mov`; it can be a win to use a memory source operand for an ALU instruction if you only need the value once or twice.)

This may be slightly worse for code-size, but is usually not worse for performance (and can be better).  If that's not good enough, write the whole function (or the whole loop) in asm so you don't have to wrestle with the compiler.

```c
int foo(char *p, int a, int b) {
    int t1,t2;  // dummy output spill slots
    int r1,r2;  // dummy output tmp registers
    int res;

    asm ("# operands: %0  %1  %2  %3  %4  %5  %6  %7  %8\n\t"
         "imull  $123, %[b], %[res]\n\t"
         "mov   %[res], %[spill1]\n\t"
         "mov   %[a], %%ecx\n\t"
         "mov   %[b], %[tmp1]\n\t"  // let the compiler allocate tmp regs, unless you need specific regs e.g. for a shift count
         "mov   %[spill1], %[res]\n\t"
    : [res] "=&r" (res),
      [tmp1] "=&r" (r1), [tmp2] "=&r" (r2),  // early-clobber
      [spill1] "=m" (t1), [spill2] "=&rm" (t2)  // allow spilling to a register if there are spare regs
      , [p] "+&r" (p)
      , "+m" (*(char (*)[]) p) // dummy in/output instead of memory clobber
    : [a] "rmi" (a), [b] "rm" (b)  // a can be an immediate, but b can't
    : "ecx"
    );

    return res;

    // p unused in the rest of the function
    // so it's really just an input to the asm,
    // which the asm is allowed to destroy
}
```

This compiles to the following asm with `gcc7.3 -O3 -m32` [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1ADNUqCMgRNi8gFQAHUvNkKmBo/IBGASnkcA7HwAMAQXmvDc%2BQXoEuHAMw8rgD0QfLoIgC2EQCe8qIEuiIKgrp4DAzyggyoBIIczm7uCsT0xL4BwaHhUbHxiQoEEbryxJjAeIIEmMR5BW5mrXkB%2BU4jhUyCEfIQ3L5cfnG63azogiA2XACsDq7cm7S7W1yHmwsbmwAsJ5snAGwnticAHBybAMIsr28Es2OFhbM8BEROlXAASWjzAx7V48cyvAAi0K2sMGiK%2Bn3ePy4vj6/0OXAiqAAbm4YZseGjNkjzrCUmkGLR0e9Md9fnj8bMiaSTrCmIjkZs9phkAAPDFfbG4lz4gncskoinw6mC2GNXRM6kSrGzSryBiYBoITDyNBNNLdeRMdKoZBMLqeJotNqCAwiFgGwSCeTRUTyFiYTDoTJLZB4RR4ZDO4DezAAOmAcaUJCtmQQ4YUaHdPw5/y5JIVQop9PSmpp5MpmDyWpZkvZMtc61RVcRG3KCO4t2Iuogg0spD%2BAIp6rLbf8Ha4XZ7JX7NmHTV81LHfgnU5x0zKs/kIXkmE0DGiAFpkNlzOZuoOycXUqXW78VxEe15Z3SbwxFwjl6viI/1xAfNY26hNa2QAO4hgysjAJ4qCpq07SdJa4aeMarRWmhKSaCa8G9A2bjQhSuh3ji/Cdt2f66JYl6uMicw8L%2BxwQNoagaFoTFURSiLWJRQFhJEMTuEEdRJO4iFMMGqCKPIESYESxCxCeqBnheHJNhS/JLrMP54D2TAvkqxFcD%2BPZWHqTCmqwFgmpZQIyfg9qYAY5gieYFksGAUg5nhTY4iK4okRyVHDM4l6tAQYgsM6QyOKMHI7s07oiIIQbuCh2FVgoklpUo7rIAQeCoJ8cWhMIhgEB53qtCBsRUElxiRbI9QwdlEwRAOxXyKB6bqC1kyGN6IGoKBKVEGEGXEKg0QjHYHYhXNTg7uZdrpJaBAaJmIHemtJqKLl%2BWFZ4oGRvGIzEqgeDBuYmgQNYdgxYUyiqA4Bj0PIXBBfdbiPRAz3yK973%2BIEvEsDkJprfa2WCEwMmZAQTDIAA1pk2S5Oh6VJUG022LNThSP2DDSJsUikCw0gOMTqDSG8pG8JkojiCa3B%2BLQxMEGTeP9gjIB%2BE8cZPPzAuCwLACcjDSBcxMRHQDjPaTUjk6QlNSMTazPWz8t46QcCwDAiAoKg5oGmQFBqAbN7dCAwC2H4pARgwXQ9JQ5js6Q5iyJo0TSCzpBmjJcgAPIep7Uje1gESsMABou/grR5XgxJVi7mCiiKSSSCHxNGJgBMZ6QBDEECXua8wbAoDTAgMHg5hrJA/aoLo%2B0sGsUiHv7ZyHhEfjHIeADqIEq/TEh0PjhPE3LCtK6KTy3IetxXMAyBRrYcYLBAuCECmTOvW8ZsWloW/WNTvD8Kz7OWJz3N%2BCvfg37fd%2B37cYtSBLpBS7cwtxhcfibJs7%2B2D/DhNhPE2LYEmLslYqxAGrM%2BWtdYQCQMJAg5BKBmnNsQOgpAgwb3QbQEeUgiZgI1oraQW9OqEAQPIKeM857yAXkvFep8Nbn1IMacSFsbpPxflLPwDg4y/wuF/BwXABHCwuLQL%2BhCJ7SEgdAphF8b58wcH4WwMsuC0GFtsC4P8n5%2BDHuA6RecYHaygHApAqC97INNobC2J4I7bGenbB2awIDOyIW7FgHsi4%2BwNn7AggcDxeLDhHKORCY4inygnZuCtk6py6F4rOOdvb50LhnfGEcy7H14IwKuNcOH10bs3VuCxDyKATsQcwqBkqHlavIXu/chCD0kLgp%2BBDx4U2kFQ2eVxbFsHkJsOMvCdhr3wEQfe8xt67yNhsLuh9y6MPJsw1hWB0EcJzlwkAtxbif1OLcWwYi1EXEAf/SR7TlZCCgYYphsD4DwJAIgyx5ijYgC4JgkZJBh4tL0UQpWTNjhHTWpQ6eXTTQl2gv0wZ8yOYsL3MsygF8cRxhxEi5FyLaBPE4ZLS%2BfCLi3C7kA2wwDRFbBOcQs5qtLkLPhcvHhezaAOCeMLWgtwHC3F/psHRXypFnPVpSp%2BXBOWnMhcwspggCqkwuEAA%3D%3D).  Note the asm-comment showing what the compiler picked for all the template operands: it picked `12(%esp)` for `%[spill1]` and  `%edi` for `%[spill2]` (because I used `"=&rm"` for that operand, so the compiler saved/restore `%edi` outside the asm, and gave it to us for that dummy operand).

```
foo(char*, int, int):
    pushl   %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    36(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %ebp
#APP
# 19 "/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler118120-55-w92ge8.v797i/example.cpp" 1
        # operands: %eax  %ebx  %esi  12(%esp)  %edi  %ebp  (%edx)  40(%esp)  44(%esp)
    imull  $123, 44(%esp), %eax
    mov   %eax, 12(%esp)
    mov   40(%esp), %ecx
    mov   44(%esp), %ebx
    mov   12(%esp), %eax

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    addl    $16, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Hmm, the dummy memory operand to tell the compiler which memory we modify seems to have resulted in dedicating a register to that, I guess because the `p` operand is early-clobber so it can't use the same register.  I guess you could risk leaving off the early-clobber if you're confident none of the other inputs will use the same register as `p`.  (i.e. that they don't have the same value).

Comment: What about `pushfd` and `popfd` instructions? Is it possible to push and pop EFLAGS without utilizing the stack?

Comment: @Cubi73: `pushf` is no different from `push %ebx` or `%rbx`.  popf is slow so you normally want to avoid it, though: https://agner.org/optimize/.  sahf / lahf can be useful but skips OF.   If you do want to push/pop, and your code might run with a red-zone (i.e. under x86-64 System V), you need `add $-128, %rsp` at the start of your asm and restore at the end.  Or compile with `-mno-red-zone` for that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, `sahf` and `lahf` are no options, because I need bit 21 (ID). I think I'm gonna stick with `-mno-red-zone` then, thanks.

Comment: @Cubi73: Oh, if you want to detect CPUID support, `#include <cpuid.h>`;  [GCC's `cpuid.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h) does all that.  Also, x86-64 guarantees that CPUID is supported so you don't need to check ID there.  And no 32-bit conventions have a red-zone.  So this ends up being a non-problem for cpuid.h.  [How do I call "cpuid" in Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14266772).  And of course you don't need `popf`, just `pop %[output]`

Answer (score 1):

The direct use of the stack pointer to reference local variables is probably caused by the use of compiler optimizations. I think you could solve the issue in a couple of ways:

- Disabling frame pointer optimizations (`-fno-omit-frame-pointer` in GCC);
- Inserting `esp` in the Clobbers so the compiler will be aware that its value is being modified (**check your compiler for compatibility**).

Comment: Just tried the second solution, works fine on one of my computer but failed another one, maybe the reason of old version of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the move into ecx within the assembly code, put the operand in ecx directly:

```
    : : "c"(foo)
```

Comment: I have edited my code, how about I have some operation in need of ecx before move instruction. And the code above is just a rough sample, what I need is push/pop operation + memroy variable as input

Comment: @prl Are you sure about that clobber rule? It works fine for me (https://godbolt.org/g/iRnDj6). It may depend on the compiler version.

Comment: @Matteo, I *was* sure, but apparently I was mistaken. I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: @MatteoPiano : Unless you put checks for appropriate compilers and versions you can't reliably use `esp` as a clobber. In older versions of many compilers it will accept `esp` as a clobber but will not do anything and won't warn you.