# Segmentation fault in Ada inline assembler

Tags: gdb, ada, inline-assembly, cpuid

I'm taking my first steps in Ada and attempting to write a package which manipulates the [CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction. I found some sequences on the OSDev wiki [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPUID) for checking the `EFLAGS.ID` bit that I'm attempting to modify into an Ada function using inline assembler, but I'm running into a persistent segfault when trying to run it. First, the package spec & body:

```
-- Specification file: Cpuid.ads --

with Standard_Types; use Standard_Types;

package Cpuid is
    
    function Is_Supported return Boolean;

end Cpuid;

-- Body file: Cpuid.adb --

with System.Machine_Code; use System.Machine_Code;

package body Cpuid is

    function Is_Supported return Boolean is
        HT  : constant Character := Character'Val(16#09#);
        LF  : constant Character := Character'Val(16#0A#);
        EAX : Unsigned_32 := 16#0000_0000#;
    begin
        Asm ("pushfq"                    & LF & HT &
             "pushfq"                    & LF & HT &
             "popq    %%rax"             & LF & HT &
             "xorq    0x00200000, %%rax" & LF & HT &
             "pushq   %%rax"             & LF & HT &
             "popfq"                     & LF & HT &
             "pushfq"                    & LF & HT &
             "popq    %%rax"             & LF & HT &
             "xorq    (%%rsp), %%rax"    & LF & HT &
             "popfq"                     & LF & HT &
             "andq    0x00200000, %%rax" & LF & HT &
             "movl    %%eax, %0",
             Outputs  => Unsigned_32'Asm_Output ("=g", EAX),
             Volatile => True);
        if EAX /= 16#0000_0000# then 
            return True; 
        else 
            return False; 
        end if;
    end Is_Supported;

end Cpuid;
```

The `Cpuid.Is_Supported` function is called by a main program which looks like this:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Standard_Types; use Standard_Types;
with Cpuid;

procedure Cpuid_Check is
    Some_Int : Unsigned_32 := 0;
begin
    if Cpuid.Is_Supported then
        Put_Line ("CPUID instruction supported on this CPU.");
    else
        Put_Line ("CPUID instruction not supported.");
    end if;
end Cpuid_Check;
```

Note that the `Standard_Types` import is just a spec-only package consisting of handwritten type definitions for `Unsigned_8`, `Unsigned_16`, and `Unsigned_32`.

When I attempt to run this program, the program fails with `PROGRAM_ERROR : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. Using GDB allows me to trace the error to a `SIGSEGV`, but I am not able to trace the violation further to a particular instruction issuance. The full debugger output is as follows:

```
Temporary breakpoint 14, 0x00000000004016e0 in cpuid_check ()
[program stopped: breakpoint-hit]
(gdb) -exec-next
Single stepping until exit from function _ada_cpuid_check,
which has no line number information.
[program running]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401ede in cpuid.is_supported ()
[program stopped: signal-received]
(gdb) -exec-next
Single stepping until exit from function cpuid__is_supported,
which has no line number information.
[program running]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffc4d3473f9 in KERNEL32!IsBadReadPtr () from C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
[program stopped: signal-received]
(gdb)
```

I've checked to ensure that I'm leaving the stack "as I found it", which, to the best of my ability, appears to be the case - the same number of pushes and pops occur within the inline assembly section. I've also rearranged the assembly sequence into `src, dest` format, as my reading on GAS indicates that is the syntax used. In the process, however, I bamboozled myself - I'm more used to Intel/NASM syntax, and GAS looks like a mess in comparison.

Is there a way to rectify this function so that it functions properly?

EDIT: Here is the disassembly dump from GDB, as noted in the comments:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function cpuid__is_supported:
   0x0000000000401ec4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401ec5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401ec8 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000401ecc <+8>: movb   $0x9,-0x1(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401ed0 <+12>:    movb   $0xa,-0x2(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401ed4 <+16>:    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401edb <+23>:    pushfq 
   0x0000000000401edc <+24>:    pushfq 
   0x0000000000401edd <+25>:    pop    %rax
=> 0x0000000000401ede <+26>:    xor    0x200000,%rax
   0x0000000000401ee6 <+34>:    push   %rax
   0x0000000000401ee7 <+35>:    popfq  
   0x0000000000401ee8 <+36>:    pushfq 
   0x0000000000401ee9 <+37>:    pop    %rax
   0x0000000000401eea <+38>:    xor    (%rsp),%rax
   0x0000000000401eee <+42>:    popfq  
   0x0000000000401eef <+43>:    and    0x200000,%rax
   0x0000000000401ef7 <+51>:    mov    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000401ef9 <+53>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401efc <+56>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401f00 <+60>:    je     0x401f09 <cpuid__is_supported+69>
   0x0000000000401f02 <+62>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401f07 <+67>:    jmp    0x401f0e <cpuid__is_supported+74>
   0x0000000000401f09 <+69>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401f0e <+74>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f0f <+75>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f10 <+76>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000401f14 <+80>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401f15 <+81>:    retq   
   0x0000000000401f16 <+82>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f17 <+83>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f18 <+84>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f19 <+85>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1a <+86>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1b <+87>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1c <+88>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1d <+89>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1e <+90>:    nop
   0x0000000000401f1f <+91>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: There haven't been any  new x86 processors that don't support CPUID for 30 years. Are you sure that you need to support ones that old?

Comment: The SIGSEGV seems to occur at the address  0x401ede. What instruction is that? (You can use objdump -D.)

Comment: @prl: More importantly, CPUID is absolutely guaranteed to work on all x86-64 CPUs, the only CPUs that can run this 64-bit code.   GCC's `cpuid.h` C header has an `#ifndef __x86_64__` around the code that checks for CPUID availability, even though it still does check this way when used in 32-bit code.

Comment: When you reach a fault inside GDB, you can also use `disas` or `layout asm` to see the faulting asm instruction.

Comment: Push in 64-bit code might be stepping on the red-zone if the Ada compiler used it.   [GCC inline assembly with stack operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853757) / [Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34520013)

Comment: @prl I realize that, but I still wanted to implement the check as an educational exercise

Comment: @prl the SIGSEGV appears to occur during execution of the `xor 0x200000,%rax` instruction, per the disassembler

Comment: Oh right, because reading from absolute address `0x200000` faults.  You want  `$0x200000`, an immediate constant.  This is AT&T syntax.  You can disassemble with an Intel-syntax disassembler (e.g. `objdump -drwC -Mintel`) to check it against the original Intel-syntax.  This would disassemble as `xor rax, qword ptr [0x200000]` which makes it easy to spot the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes that successfully fixed the issue - replacement of the `$` prefix on the two `xorq`/`andq` instructions causes the `Is_Supported` function to return `True`. If you post this as a stub answer I'm happy to accept it as the solution.

Comment: `return EAX /= 16#0000_0000#;` would be better (more idiomatic) Ada